# pressing super key twice switches windows as alt+tab would

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using windows 10.

When I have a fullscreen window in focus then press the super key to bring up the windows menu then press it again to get rid of it it switches to the next window as alt+tab would, it only happens in fullscreen so it doesn't work to repeat this procedure to return to the fullscreen window. This started happening maybe a year ago, it hasn't always been that way.

Is this intended to happen? I don't see any reason why it should and I can't find any mention of this problem so I can only assume that it is not happening to everyone.
Not sure what's going on with this.

Comment: I don't see this behavior with **Explorer** in fullscreen. The Start Menu and Taskbar appear when the key is pressed, but then disappear when pressed again, and **Explorer** in fullscreen is still displayed and is the active window.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are having problems with Windows 10's `Task View` feature. Using the Task View feature, you can switch between open windows and virtual desktops. Your keyboard's `super` key or the Windows key activates Task View, which shows thumbnails of all open windows.

The last window you used before opening Task View will be displayed if you press the Windows key once more or click outside the Task View window. When Task View is closed, if you were in a full-screen window when it was first opened, it will move on to the following open window in the list.

Microsoft designed this behaviour, which is a feature of the Windows 10 operating system. Try modifying the settings in the Task View section of the Windows Settings app if you'd prefer to disable this behaviour.

Select `Settings` (the gear icon) from the Start menu to access these settings. Afterward, select `System` before selecting `Multitasking`. You can change the behaviour of Task View here, as well as decide whether to enable or disable it completely.